# Make component width dynamic

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The essence of my problem is that when the screen changes, not all components are resized. And thus the page looks ugly. And I would like all the components to change accordingly.

Now more....On the page I have four components (Breadcrumbs, FilterMethod, Filter, LinkedTable).

Styles are applied to them as follows (all this can be seen in the code, but I will explain for a better understanding):

sx={ContainerStyle} --> Breadcrumbs

sx={StyleSideBar} --> FilterMethod

sx={StyleFilterAndLinkedTable} --> Filter and LinkedTable

Thus, when I resize the page, the ContainerStyle and StyleFilterAndLinkedTable styles work out well (their components resize to match the page size). But the style component StyleSideBar remains static, that is, it does not change in width, and with any size changes, the page remains the same. I would like it to also change according to page size changes.

Yes, I understand that I wrote the minWidth: '350px' and maxWidth: '300px' parameters. But otherwise I don't know how to set the width of this component.

Please tell me how can I solve this issue.

Its code:

```
   return(
    <Grid sx={ContainerStyle}>
                  
        <Grid container spacing={1} sx={{ width: '100vw', height: '10vh' }}>
            <Grid sx={StyleSideBar}  >
                <CardContent>
                    <Table>
                        <TableBody>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <FilterMethod
                                        isExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded}
                                        setIsExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}
                                        setMethods={props.setMethods}
                                    />
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
          
            <Grid container xs={12} sm={7} lg={9} sx={StyleFilterAndLinkedTable}>
                <Filter
                    pageName='Device list'
                    showBackToButton={false}
                    showFilter={true}
                    
                />
                {!isNaN(amountOfPages) && !isNaN(amountOfItems)?
                    <LinkedTable
                        filterData={filterData}
                        applyFilter={applyFilter}
                        cursor='device'
                        
                    />
                : ''}
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
);
```

Comment: Can you share a working Fiddle link for your scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use width percentages or a flex box layout. When using width percentages, your component will take up x% of the screen, when using flex, it will automatically calculate each component's width in order to take the maximum available space, I suggest you read this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and for percentages https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp